# Android Properties Window

Tags: android, eclipse, class, properties

If I right click on my project and select properties.  Then select android properties on the left side of the screen I am given a window where I can change project build target or add a library.  The problem is none of my changes appear to be "sticking" in this screen when I hit apply or ok.

For example I go into the screen to add a library project:

[image: Step 1:]

Then I hit apply, then ok.  When I go back into the screen none of my changes have been applied:

[image: Step 2:]

This is a problem because I want to reference a library project in my main project.  Whenever I try to reference one of the classes in my library project from my main project I get a class not found exception.  Also whenever I run my project it says the libray-project.apk is not found in the console window?

Any suggestions or is this possibly a bug in eclipse or the android tools?

This bug has been reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17673&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `default.properties` file is not read-only. This file is located in root folder of your Android project.

**UPDATE:** I actually tried making this file read-only and can see exactly the same behavior, but on Ubuntu. Don't have access to Windows machine now. This should probably be reported as bug.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. It worked.  I think the file was marked read only when I set up my SVN.  How do I report this as a bug? Google Groups? (I will mark this as the correct answer in 2 minutes)

Comment: There is an official bugtracker: http://b.android.com/. You should create new issue there. I've made a quick search myself and didn't find anything like this. Can you please also include a link to this new issue in your question (as an edit)? So other developers know its officially tracked.